# Attach to the specific running process inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, shell, nginx, containers

While the nginx might not be a good example for this case but there would be similar cases that we will need to run a process and access it inside a container without recreating/rerunning it.

I already run nginx as a container using following command:

```
docker run -d --name=my_container nginx:latest
```

I didn't active terminal or interactive mode during docker run command. Now, I want to run a bash (using `docker exec ...` ) in detach mode and then attach (using `docker attach ...` ) to it later.

As you know we can run new process inside a container, e.g:

```
docker exec -itd my_container bash
```

By this way a new bash process will run inside this container.

**Now my question is that how to attach to this process later?**

I tried to run following command but it just shows the nginx live log:

```
docker attach my_nginx2
```

Comment: `docker attach` attaches to the main process (the one that started when you created the container with `docker run`). You can't "re-attach" to a process you've started with `docker exec`, but you can always just `docker exec` without the `-d` option to start a new interactive shell.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, there is no way for this case?

Comment: How would you do this if Docker wasn't involved; start a shell inside an Nginx server process?  Why do you think you need to keep a long-running shell inside your HTTP server?  (I suspect there may be better tools than `docker exec` for your needs.)

Comment: While the nginx might not be a good examples for running a process inside a container but there would be many cases that we need run a process inside a container such as replication, monitoring, debugging, .... .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your use case, you can do this :

```
docker run -itd --name=my_container nginx:latest bash -i -c 'nginx; bash -i'
```

this allows you to do :

```
docker attach my_container
```

you can detach from a container and leave it running using the CTRL-p CTRL-q key sequence.

Comment: Hi Philippe, Thanks for your answer. It is not the case in fact. .Let assume you forgot to run the container with bash at the first time, Now, You don't want to rerun a new one.

Comment: I don't quite get what you meant by your comment.

Comment: I want to attach to the process which is created after run command by exec. Your answer is fine if we run the bash during run command, but it is not my case.

Comment: It's `NOT` possible to `attach` to an existing session started by `docker exec`. As workaround, can you start a bash session at start, and attach to it later ? if not, why ?

Comment: This is your answer for my question "It's NOT possible to attach to an existing session started by docker exec".

"As workaround, can you start a bash session at start, and attach to it later ? if not, why ?" Yes it is possible. It is not about bash it can be any running job. Even for the bash I'm not sure it is the same bash or different.